# How to lower the volume in a specific time interval with ffmpeg.exe

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to lower the volume in a specific time interval with ffmpeg.exe . Let's say I have a 5 minutes long video and I want to lower the volume between 00:01:30 and 00:02:00. I read that we can use different parameters at the same time but I couldn't figure it out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with filter complex:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]null[out2];[0:a]atrim=duration=90[a];\
[0:a]atrim=start=90:duration=30,volume=0.1,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[b];[a][b]concat=v=0:a=1[c];\
[0:a]atrim=start=120,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[d];[c][d]concat=v=0:a=1[out1]" \
-acodec mp2 -map [out1] -map [out2] out.mp4
```

It lowers volume to 0.1 (1.0 is full) on segment from 90 sec to 120 sec. How it works? It does nothing with video stream (filter null) just to include it in filter graph. Then trims first 90 seconds from audio stream, then trims 30 seconds (90-120) from audio stream and reduces volume to 0.1. Then combines last 2 audio streams with concat. Then again trims the rest audio stream and again combines it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you ptQa ,i tried this but there is an error.It works for silence but video is not playing as normal after 120 second.It seems like fast forwarding the video.How can i fix that issue?

Comment: Whoops, my bad. I forgot about PTS, please try updated command with apts filter.

Comment: Thank you very much! :) It works!! :) You are genius! :)

Comment: Hi again,

I'm trying to lower the volume between 10 and 20 seconds.It lowers the volume on 10 seconds but it doesn't start again on 20..It starts somewhere after 50 seconds but its not synchronized.The sound what i hear on 50 seconds it should be on 20 second mark. How can i solve this problem?

I'm a Windows user.

Here's my code : http://pastebin.com/fbpXFmiZ

Comment: You should use asetpts every time you use atrim with start option.

Comment: Can you please show me how to use it? Thank you..

Comment: In my answer there is an example with asetpts, is not it?

Comment: Yeah,i'm sorry.I don't know why but i copied this code without aspts..I'm sorry for disturbing you..Thank you very much again.

Comment: probably easier solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38106756/1538014